# C# BufferedGraphics Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, gdi

My code has the following form:

```
while (Globals.Running)
{
    if ((Form.Visible == false) || (Form.ContainsFocus == false) || (Form.Enabled == false))
    {
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    else
    {
        Update();
        Draw();
    }

    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

When I look at the process in the Task Manager, I see the memory consumed increases by 8K each second.

If I comment out the `Draw()` call, memory is stable. Therefore, memory is leaking inside `Draw`. Here is how that method looks like:

```
private static void Draw()
{
    BufferedGraphics.Graphics.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    //Engine.Draw(BufferedGraphics.Graphics);
    BufferedGraphics.Render();
    ++FPS;
}
```

So, even without me drawing anything, memory is lost. If I comment out `.Clear` line, it still leaks. If I comment out `.Render` line, it still leaks. If I comment out both of those, it stops leaking.

`BufferedGraphics` is initialized in the constructor like this:

```
BufferedGraphics = BufferedGraphicsContext.Allocate(Graphics.FromHwnd(Form.Handle), Form.ClientRectangle);
```

So, my question is, why is rendering nothing/clearing the graphics context leaking memory? Or is there something else at play here?

Comment: Most likely you just don't understand how .NET's memory management works. .NET uses a garbage collector that only collects memory once in a while - unless the "leaked" memory gets over about 10-20 MiB, you probably don't have a problem there. There's a couple of things that are likely generating a few objects here and there, causing the memory usage to increase somewhat - even `Application.DoEvents`  in your "game loop" is sub-optimal. If you're doing real-time rendering, it might be worth it to have a look at a graphics library like SharpDX/SlimDX or such.

Comment: I see. I looked into SlimDX but since I need nothing intensive, just a few bitmaps and some text, I figured this would do. I guess I'll change to `Dispatcher.Invoke` like PieterSchool and DJ KRAZE said.

Comment: Well, `Dispatcher.Invoke` still has memory overhead. Think about it differently instead - do you really want to have real-time rendering at fixed FPS, or do you want event-based rendering instead? If real-time, keep your loop as is, it's fine. If event-based, both Winforms and WPF work great, no need to use a game loop just for the sake of it.

Comment: True... At first I thought I would need real-time, but now... You're right, I don't really need it. Thanks all for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use application.doEvents! Use a dispatcher to update the UI whilst operating on a different thread, it wil prevent blocking of the UI and changes won't leak memory

Example:
[Dispatcher.Invoke to update UI Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499316/dispatcher-invoke-to-update-ui-control)

Comment: I agree do not use `Application.DoEvents();` it's not a good practice

Comment: You didn't read deep enough into it - this is an obvious game loop, not an attempt at cooperative multi-tasking in Winforms. `Application.DoEvents()` loops have been used for that for some time. They are not the best way to make a game loop, but they're not all that bad either.

Comment: Application.DoEvents() is blocking. When something has been done a certain way for a long time doesn't make it a good choise.

Comment: But you're missing the point - `Invoke` will not really help at all. In fact, it is a great way to kill any chance of having decent performance - it will cause lots of unnecessary allocations and the OP most likely doesn't even have any controls to update. I might be wrong, but I think he's simply making a game in GDI+ - unless he does combine custom rendering with actual winforms/WPF controls, `Invoke` is worse than useless.